# slideshow on website hosted on aws s3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Problem: slideshow on website which is hosted on AWS S3 not working as expected.

Is this because it's not considered "static content"? The website itself consists of css, html, and javascript.

My website, https://www.fastsecure.website/ , is hosted on AWS S3 (in addition I am using Route 53 and Cloudfront). Everything looks good except at the bottom of the page (just above "Get in Touch" in the black box section) you should see testimonial slideshow, buy I don't see it on Chrome, Safari, or Vivaldi.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] with the snippet tool

Comment: ok thank you for the response. I am not sure what snippet tool is but should I paste the code here or upload the css and js files here?

Comment: The snippet tool provides you a way to paste the CSS and JS files. Please be aware that you should aim for a **minimal** example. Just copy/pasting all your existing code is not minimal

Comment: "Static content" content means content the server does not itself modify or generate, and unless you are trying to run code on S3 (which isn't possible -- you can't e.g. run php scripts on S3) this should be unrelated... but check your browser console, because you do have at least one JavaScript error.  `Uncaught ReferenceError: loadGoogleMap is not defined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js:140)`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you for this error report. And this error says it's the file named "custom.js" and it's on line 140! that's great news.   I don't know what the code snippet is or how to use it here. But your explanation of static content helps.

Comment: are you fixed the slide show issue ? Now  I think `Get in Touch` section working properly

Comment: This is good idea to advertise our business websites